# how to compile ffmpeg with enabling libsrt

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg following [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) guide, it doesn't show how to enable libsrt, I tried the following configuration, but got error `libavformat/libsrt.c:24:10: fatal error: srt/srt.h: No such file or directory`.

`./configure --prefix=/home/hao/repo/Transcoder/Release/ffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-demuxer='mpegts,mpegvideo,image2' --enable-muxer=mpegts --enable-protocol='file,udp,rtp,srt' --enable-filter=overlay --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --disable-doc`

Answer (score 10):

It does not appear you are following the [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), but if you were to do so then compiling instructions for Haivision SRT could look like:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Haivision/srt.git
mkdir srt/build
cd srt/build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" -DENABLE_C_DEPS=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DENABLE_STATIC=ON ..
make
make install
```

Then continue with the guide. When you get to the `ffmpeg` section make sure to add `--enable-libsrt` to the configure line.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `--pkg-config-flags="--static"` to your FFMpeg configure line, otherwise pkg-config can't find the static libs.

Comment: This would be for a link time failure :)