# How to configure ffmpeg with libsrt (Secure Reliable Transport) protocol?

Tags: ffmpeg, protocols, configuration-files, patch, pkg-config

I want to configure ffmpeg with libsrt (Secure Reliable Transport) protocol on linux-Ubuntu OS, I followed the steps from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967706/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-with-enabling-libsrt)

But when run `$./configure --enable-libsrt` command it gives me an error:

**`ERROR: srt >= 1.3.0 not found using pkg-config`**

I modified the configuration file, it executed the above command but when i run `$ make` command it end up with the following errors:

```
LD  ffmpeg_g
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_socket'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_bind'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_getsockopt'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_close'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_epoll_add_usock'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_startup'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_connect'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_epoll_release'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_listen'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_getlasterror'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_getlasterror_str'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_cleanup'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_setsockopt'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_sendmsg'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_clearlasterror'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_epoll_wait'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_epoll_remove_usock'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_epoll_create'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_recvmsg'
libavformat/libavformat.so: undefined reference to `srt_accept'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:108: recipe for target 'ffmpeg_g' failed
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

What are exact steps to enable libsrt with ffmpeg ? Am i missing anything ? Is there any patch i have to add to existing ffmpeg source ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The configure script is meant to evaluate the presence and suitability of dependencies. Don't expect to evade them by modifying the script !! What is your srt version?

Comment: The srt version is 1.3.2

Comment: Are you sure you properly installed (make install) SRT ?

Comment: @thekamilz SRT installed correctly

Comment: We HAD problem with proper installation in the version before 1.3.1, it was due to using `lib` explicitly instead of `GNUInstallDirs`. In version 1.3.2 it should be fixed. If you have a problem reported as "pkg-config", simply try to do `pkg-config --libs srt`. If you have any invalid result, please check if PKG_CONFIG_PATH points to a location where SRT is installed, and if this is ok, please file a bug on https://github.com/Haivision/srt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answer you referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50975754/1109017) to assumes the question asker was following the [Ubuntu compile guide on the FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) (because they claimed to be doing so). The compile guide "installs" external libraries into `~/ffmpeg_build` for a [variety of reasons](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#FAQ). The libsrt instructions in that answer does the same to fit with the wiki article. Therefore, it is expected that you will use the additional compilation options as shown in the wiki to deal with this when compiling `ffmpeg`.

1. Undo whatever changes you made to `configure`.
2. Follow the linked answer and compile libsrt if you haven't already.
3. Now compile `ffmpeg`.

   ```
   make distclean
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --enable-libsrt --pkg-config-flags="--static"
   ```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to use most of those extra options then omit `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/ffmpeg_build"` when compiling libsrt.