# Compiled FFmpeg not accepting -c:v and -c:a

Tags: ffmpeg

I compiled FFmpeg with libsrt, with the online compile guide. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu & [how to compile ffmpeg with enabling libsrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967706/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-with-enabling-libsrt)

It seems to compile correctly.

```
ffmpeg version N-96575-g843c24a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
configuration: --prefix=/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/ubuntu/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libsrt --enable-nonfree
libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
libavcodec     58. 67.100 / 58. 67.100
libavformat    58. 37.100 / 58. 37.100
libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
libavfilter     7. 72.100 /  7. 72.100
libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

But when running this command to convert a incoming SRT stream to HLS, it doesn't know the -c:a command. When switching the order, it runs that it doesn't know about the -c:v command.

```
ffmpeg -re -i srt://0.0.0.0:25000?pkt_size=1316&mode=listener -c:a copy -c:v copy -strict -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event stream.m3u8
```

```
~$ ffmpeg -re -i srt://0.0.0.0:25000?pkt_size=1316&mode=listener -c:a copy -c:v copy -strict -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event stream.m3u8
[2] 9930
ffmpeg version N-96575-g843c24a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/ubuntu/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libsrt --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.100 / 58. 67.100
  libavformat    58. 37.100 / 58. 37.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 72.100 /  7. 72.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
-c:a: command not found

[2]+  Stopped                 ffmpeg -re -i srt://0.0.0.0:25000?pkt_size=1316
```

I have searched the issue, but I could not find anything similar.
Does someone know what I have missed in the setup?

Everything is manually compiled through the guide, this was the final command I run to compile FFmpeg:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
cd ffmpeg && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libaom \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-libsrt \
  --enable-nonfree && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install && \
hash -r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with ffmpeg. The shell treats 1316 as the end of the command and `&` as the background operator.

Enclose the full URL in quotes to avoid this.

```
"srt://0.0.0.0:25000?pkt_size=1316&mode=listener"
```