# SRT protocol not found - Raspbery Pi 4 via ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, protocols, raspberry-pi4, srt

We tried to stream from a rasp Pi 4 via SRT, but we got a error: "protocol not found". Our command line is:

```
ffplay srt://127.0.0.1:9500?mode=listener&latency=20000
```

We tried the following guides:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
[how to compile ffmpeg with enabling libsrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967706/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-with-enabling-libsrt)
https://www.undergroundnews.dk/index.php/item/107-rtmp-eller-srt-streaming

Those guides worked so far and compiled but we still got the error message.

Do you have any ideas how to get the srt protocol working on a pi via ffmpeg?

Comment: Your link to trac.ffmpeg.org doesn't mention libsrt (anymore?). As of Aug. 2021, I have not been able to find a Linux ffplay binary compiled with support for SRT. ffmpeg supports it in the [static builds from johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), but these come without ffplay. And the nightly build of VLC for Linux don't seem to support it either. Your best bet seems to be using [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/download) (or a Windows or Mac version of VLC).

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:
`ffplay "srt://127.0.0.1:9500?mode=caller&latency=20000"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **watch** an srt stream with `ffplay`, you need to use the "caller" mode, as shown in the answer by @imyw.

But you may also need to compile ffplay yourself. I have not found a Linux binary of ffplay which supports srt. You can check with `ffplay -version | grep libsrt`.

If you want to **stream** over srt, you have to use `ffmpeg`. But your ffmpeg binary may also not have libsrt enabled. Check with `ffmpeg -version | grep libsrt`.

If it isn't enabled in your version of ffmpeg, you can get a static build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ which has libsrt enabled. Then you can use ffmpeg to stream (from port 9500 as in your example) with a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "$YourVideo" -f mpegts "srt://0.0.0.0:9500?mode=listener"
```

Or you could try [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) which also supports the srt protocol.